# Can not open sites using wireguard VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to setup wireguard VPN in Ubuntu 20.04. I do the following:

```
sudo cp wgIoffeVPN2smirnovdm.conf /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
sudo wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 172.16.245.37/24 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] ip -4 route add 194.85.224.0/20 dev wg0
[#] ip -4 route add 172.16.0.0/16 dev wg0
[#] ip -4 route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev wg0
```

It seems to work:

```
sudo wg show wg0
interface: wg0
  public key: Rh4CnAexQbBJ2hBueYwkzoElFLoYumKFsQqKId02hUk=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 37273

peer: A7LH7h/xDlLwfwtnPdGE8Lwe9sF5xW66k/Yrd/uTOxk=
  endpoint: 194.85.224.5:44886
  allowed ips: 172.16.0.0/16, 194.85.224.0/20, 10.0.0.0/8
  latest handshake: 23 seconds ago
  transfer: 92 B received, 1.28 MiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

However I can not open any site in my browser and there is no ping:

```
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

The same config file works perfectly on mac and android. What can be a problem with Ubuntu?

Comment: Here is a solution: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/auuvn5/problem_excluding_private_networks_in_allowedips/)

Comment: Check your firewall settings probably?